# Unable to determine and spot in an array and skip ahead in the array

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I'm writing a program to read a barcode from an image which then produces an array of 1's and 0's from which I produce and array of numbers between 0-9. To do this I have to take the original array in 7 bit sequences and compare them against another array to figure out which number that pattern represents. Half way through the barcode there are 5 lines which separate the left pattern from the right pattern (which is meant to be the optical inverse of the left). I'm having problems with it catching the middle of the array and jumping ahead five spots. It's 95 bits 6 of which are the opening and closing patters and do not represent numbers and then the 5 bit pattern in the middle. I'm catching it at 45 and jumping it ahead to 50 but this isn't producing the correct results. I checked several times to make sure that these are the correct values and they seem to be but they aren't working. Here is the original set of 1s and 0s in string form:

```
10100110010010011011110101000110110001010111101010100010010010001110100111001011001101101100101
```

Here is the code num is the original array (what is above), numTemp is the current 7 bit pattern I am working with (and a subset of num).

```
   int tempIndex = 0;

    if (start == 45) {
            start = 50;

        }
        while (start < end) {
            numTemp[tempIndex] = num[start];
            start++;
            tempIndex++;
        }
        end = end + 7;

        System.out.println(" ");
        for (int x = 0; x < 7; x++) {
            System.out.print(numTemp[x]);
        }
```

There is a larger loop that encloses this and more but I didn't think it too relevant. Basically start starts at 3 and end starts at 10 and both keep incrementing until the larger loop has run 12 times (the number of numbers represented by the 7 bit patterns).

As you can see I print out each numTemp pattern here is the output:

```
>0011001 
>0010011 
>0111101 
>0100011 
>0110001 
>0101111 
>**1001111** 
>0010010 
>0100011 
>1010011 
>1001011 
>0011011
```

The first 6 patterns are correct but the next pattern (in bold) should be 0111011 consequently the following patterns are incorrect.

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: What is the exact format of the original array?

Comment: What do you mean? It is an integer array that is 1 dimensional.

Comment: Knowing the format is important; if it is an array of integers with only zeroes or ones in it, then you may want to look at the `BitSet` class

Comment: Correct. 0 representing a white line and 1 representing a black line.

Comment: Unfortunately since this is an assignment I am required to use arrays.

Comment: Nowhere in that original set of 1s and 0s do I see five consecutive 1s. Nor is the second half an inverse of the first half. Bad data perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about the bold value, cause as far as I see it in a range 50 - 57 I get 1000100, but any way this is what I came up with, maybe it will help you. I used data as a String, you can remodel it using arrays or what ever you need.

```
for (int i = 3; i < (CODE.length() - 3); i += 7) {
        if (i == 45) {
            i = 43;
        } else {
            printOut("line " + i + " - " + (i+7) + " = "+ CODE.substring(i, i+7));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ah, yes it is supposed to be what you said I accidentally put the the left version of that. I'll have to wait until later tonight to try your solution though I think it is a little beyond my knowledge at this point.